# loadViewIfNeeded before iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to create and load a `UIViewController` before inserting it as a subview into another `UIViewController`.

In iOS 9 I could do `myController.loadViewIfNeeded()`. What is a good workaround for iOS 8?

It seems that `myController.view.hidden = myController.view.hidden` works but it seems like a dangerous hack.

Comment: The reason that this little 'hack' works is that view controllers load their views at first access (so even a `print(vc.view)` would load the view) _but_ there are proper mechanisms for managing child controllers in case you are implementing a [custom container view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW12)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many ways in which you can force view controller to load its view. In fact, the most common way (as far as I know) is to access `view` property of the view controller.

```
_ = viewController.view
```

I wouldn't treat this as a hack. In fact, Apple's documentation states that accessing the view property when it is equal to `nil` results in loading the requested view. This means that proposed solution is safe and should work as intended even with future releases of the iOS. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view):

> The view stored in this property represents the root view for the view controller's view hierarchy. The default value of this property is nil.
>
> If you access this property and its value is currently nil, the view controller automatically calls the loadView method and returns the resulting view.